# Involution On elliptic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

In an elliptic curve E given by $y^2=x^3 + ax^2 +bx+ c$ and origin at the point of infinity, why does the map $i$ sending $(x, y)$ to $(x, -y)$ send $i(P)=-P$, where $-P$ denotes the inverse of $P$ under the the group operation on $E$?

One way is to use the explicit formula in terms of x,y for the inverse, I suppose.

But in the book I’m reading (Hida’s Geometric Modular Forms) the group structure on $E$ is not defined via the usual secant line process,but via the isomorphism $E$ with $Pic^0$ sending $P$ to $I(P)^{-1} \otimes I(O)$ where $I(P)$ is the ideal sheaf of the point $P$ and $O$ is the origin. Somehow it seems, from the highlighted part in the excerpt below, we need to use something about how the group operation interacts with the a non-vanishing 1-form - we’ve seen earlier that all such are invariant under pullback via addition/translation by given point of $E$
[image]